# How to view exceptions when debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, exception, logging

I'm using NLog like this

```
try
{
    // ... some code
}
catch(AException ex)
{
    logger.ErrorException(ex.Message, ex);
}
```

But I want to see the exception when debugging. So I tried:

```
#if !DEBUG
    try
    {
#endif
        // ... some code
#if !DEBUG
    }
    catch(AException ex)
    {
        logger.ErrorException(ex.Message, ex);
    }
#endif
```

Is there a neater way of doing that?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn on First Chance Exceptions: CTRL-ALT-E (tick the thrown column for CLR exceptions)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it this way. It's better to turn on Exception notification on Debug->Exceptions. This way you will see exceptions when they are created even if they are handled latter on.